# Shell Script to copy files from linux machine to windows machine

Tags: shell

I would like to copy a file from Linux machine to Windows machine periodically (both the machines are accessed remotely).

Suppose I have the following.
Linux machine named host1 and the username is user1
Windows machine named host2 and the username is user2. The windows machine also has the password to logged in.

I want to copy files from `/home/admin` of host1 to `D:\admin` of host2.

Can anyone please help me in creating a shell script to perform this task.

Comment: It is not the virtual machine, right? You mean copy files from guest to host?

Answer (score 1):

One way to copy files from one machine to other is using `SCP` utility.

```
scp username@host_ip:/home/user/your_file /cygdrive/D/admin/
```

Copy the file "foobar.txt" from a remote host to the local host

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /cygdrive/D/admin
```

---

**Simple generic command.**

Copy the file to the /home/project/ directory on your device. Note: provide IP is just an example.

```
scp youfile.txt user@192.168.10.2:project/
```

I suggest you check this [SCP commands](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

Comment: I tried these but it is not working..

tried to just ftp as:


ftp username@host


It is establishing the connection after entering the password.




I would like to include the password also while FTPying

Comment: What error you got while using scp, are you sure your using correct IP, and providing the correct path?

Comment: Connection was getting timed out. I used ftp command and is working now. Following is the code I used.




HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
mput *.tmp
END_SCRIPT







I also wanted to hide the password from the script. Any other suggestion please ...

Comment: @danglingpointer what  is cygdrive referring to ? I am attempting the same but unsure what part of the path that would be ?  I have  scp root@10.177.555.204:/home/golide/jmeter/HtmlReport/index.html /D:/linuxshares but its not working ..